# React Router auth-flow doesn't redirect on invalid/expired token

Tags: authentication, reactjs, client-side, react-router

## My issue

I'm following the [auth-flow example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow) from the react-router repo for client side authentication.

Everything works great except in the case of an expired or invalid token.  If there is no token in local storage the user is redirected to the login page just fine.  However, if there is a token in local storage (even if the token doesn't validate on the server) redirects do not work.

Thanks for your help

## The Code

#### index.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import App from './components/App'
import Request from './components/Request'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Dashbord from './components/Dashboard'
import AddFeature from './components/AddFeature'
import styles from './styles-common/layout.css'
import auth from './auth'

const appSection = document.createElement('div')

appSection.id = 'root'

document.body.insertBefore(appSection, document.body.firstChild);

function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}

ReactDom.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={requireAuth}>
      <IndexRoute component={Dashbord} />
      <Route path="request/:id" component={Request} />
      <Route path="/new-request" component={AddFeature} />
    </Route>

    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  </Router>
), appSection)
```

#### App.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../Header'
import DropDownMenu from '../DropDownMenu'
import styles from './styles.css'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header>
          <DropDownMenu />
        </Header>

        <div className={styles.contentContainer}>
          <main className={styles.content}>

            {this.props.children}
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

#### auth.js

```
import request from 'superagent'

export default {
  login(email, pass, cb) {
    cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1]
    if (localStorage.token) {
      if (cb) cb(true)
      this.onChange(true)
      return
    }
    authenticate(email, pass, (res) => {
      if (res.authenticated) {
        localStorage.token = res.token
        localStorage.user_firstname = res.user_firstname
        localStorage.user_lastname = res.user_lastname
        localStorage.user_id = res.user_id
        if (cb) cb(true)
        this.onChange(true)
      } else {
        if (cb) cb(false)
        this.onChange(false)
      }
    })
  },

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.token
  },

  logout(cb) {
    delete localStorage.token
    if (cb) cb()
    this.onChange(false)
  },

  loggedIn() {
    return !!localStorage.token
  },

  onChange() {}
}

function authenticate (email, pass, callback) {
  let body = {email: email, password: pass}

  request
    .post('api/auth')
    .send(body)
    .end((err, res) => {
      let result = JSON.parse(res.text)
      if (result.success) {
        callback({
          authenticated: true,
          user_id: result.user_id,
          user_firstname: result.user_firstname,
          user_lastname: result.user_lastname,
          token: result.token
        })
      } else {
        callback({ authenticated: false} )
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve this.  I just realized that auth.js only hits the server for authorization during login and not during any any other client side events. I will work on this a bit later in the day and I will post up my code in case this can help anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

## My Solution

**auth.js**

```
import request from 'superagent'

export default {
  login(email, pass, cb) {
    cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1]
    if (localStorage.token && this.activeUser()) {
      if (cb) cb(true)
      this.onChange(true)
      return
    }
    authenticate(email, pass, (res) => {
      if (res.authenticated) {
        localStorage.token = res.token
        localStorage.user_firstname = res.user_firstname
        localStorage.user_lastname = res.user_lastname
        localStorage.user_id = res.user_id
        localStorage.last_active = Date.now() // <--------------
        if (cb) cb(true)
        this.onChange(true)
      } else {
        if (cb) cb(false)
        this.onChange(false)
      }
    })
  },

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.token
  },

  logout(cb) {
    delete localStorage.token
    delete localStorage.user_firstname
    delete localStorage.user_lastname
    delete localStorage.user_id
    delete localStorage.last_active
    if (cb) cb()
    this.onChange(false)
  },

  // *--- Added this method ---*
  activeUser() {
    let i = parseInt(localStorage.last_active)

    return (
      localStorage.last_active &&
      (i + 3600000) >= Date.now() ?
      localStorage.last_active = Date.now() :
      false
    )
  },


  loggedIn() {
    return !!localStorage.token
  },

//...
```

**index.jsx**

```
//...

function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn() || !auth.activeUser()) {  // <--- Validate active 
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}

//...
```